# Is there a way to use `event.target` to target specific sub-components and alter their style?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, event-handling

Is there a way to use `event.target` to target specific sub-components and alter their style?

```
export default function Component(props) {
  function MouseOver(event) {
    event.target.style.boxShadow =
      event.target.className === "container" &&
      "4px 6px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
    event.target.className.style.color = "#000";
  }
  function MouseOut(event) {
    event.target.style.boxShadow = "none";
    event.target.className.style.color = "#fff";
  }

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        ...Styles.root,
        background: `url(${props.image})`,
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        ...props.style,
      }}
      onMouseOver={MouseOver}
      onMouseOut={MouseOut}
      className={"container"}
    >
      <span style={Styles.title} className={"title"}>
        {props.title}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}

const Styles = {
  root: {
    display: "flex",
  },
  title: {
    width: "100%",
    display: "flex",
    color: "#FFF",
    boxShadow: "none",
  },
};
```

I want the title to change color when the mouse is over the component. Can `event.target` be used to target specific sub-components and alter their style?

This is the error that I get

```
categoriesCard.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'color')
    at MouseOut (component.js:10:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4161:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4210:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4274:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4288:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9038:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9070:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9083:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9094:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:9285:1
```

Answer (score 0):

"event.target" in your code is "MouseEvent" so it's not possible to change styles

why don't you add class name by using useState ?

```
export default function Component(props) {
  const [onMouseOver, setOnMouseOver] = useState(false);
  function MouseOver(event) {
    setOnMouseOver(true);
    // event.target.style.boxShadow =
    //   event.target.className === 'container' &&
    //   '4px 6px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
    // event.target.className.style.color = '#000'; # Write this code in YourOwnClassName class
  }
  function MouseOut(event) {
    setOnMouseOver(false);
    // event.target.style.boxShadow = 'none';
    // event.target.className.style.color = '#fff'; # Write this code in YourOwnClassName class
  }

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        ...Styles.root,
        background: `url(${props.image})`,
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        ...props.style,
      }}
      onMouseOver={MouseOver}
      onMouseOut={MouseOut}
      className={onMouseOver ? 'container YourOwnClassName' :'container'}
    >
      <span style={Styles.title} className={'title'}>
        {props.title}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

actually, the greatest way to style is using "hover" css selector